# Recharger un portable - la batterie ou le crédit?

Tags: vocabulaire

Si quelqu’un dit « je dois recharger mon portable », penseriez-vous qu’il parle de la batterie ou du crédit ?

Utilise-t-on le mot « recharger » pour tous les deux ? Comment faites-vous pour deviner le sens juste ? Et/ou comment dites-vous pour impliquer le sens juste ?

(En Irlande, nous dirions souvent « top-up my phone » pour le crédit, et « (re)charge my phone» pour la batterie.)

Comment: Il y a ambiguïté, mais j'avoue qu'en France, recharger le crédit de son forfait téléphonique n'est plus vraiment d'actualité. On parle alors en général d'une option de forfait (extension étranger par exemple, ou quand on a des systèmes pré-payés pour des appels à l'étranger).

Comment: @Larme Les forfaits bloqués (prépayés) sont quand même assez utilisés en France, en particulier chez les plus jeunes. C'est bien de ceux-là dont il s'agit ici.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il s'agit très certainement de la batterie car sinon la formule la plus courante est plutôt :

> Je dois recharger mon forfait.

aussi

> Je dois [recharger ma carte](https://www.lapostemobile.fr/offres/prepaye-classique).

Answer (score 5):

La façon la plus évidente de comprendre cette phrase est: « Je n'ai presque plus de batterie. »

Comme alternative, on dirait plutôt « recharger mon crédit » (ou d'autres expressions).

Cependant, il est possible que quelqu'un utilise maladroitement « Je dois recharger mon portable » pour dire qu'il doit insérer du crédit.

Answer (score 2):

Utilisable dans les 2 cas. Possiblement ambiguë sans contexte mais peut dépendre du pays. Dans mon coin il n'y a pas vraiment de système de crédit.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que c'est la batterie qu'elle recharge...
S'il s'agissait de crédit je pense qu'elle aurait du employer d'autres termes...
Par exemple: "Recharger son compte", "Ajouter de credit"...